# django error HomePageView' object has no attribute 'META' windows 7

Tags: python, django

**Error log:**

```
error HomePageView' object has no attribute 'META'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from hello.views import HomePageView
urlpatterns = (
   url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
import textwrap 
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.utils import timezone 
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.views.generic.base import View 

class HomePageView(View): 
    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        c = {} 
        return render(request, 'welcome.html', c)
```

**welcome.html**

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Greetings to Django</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1 style="color:green;" align="center">Greetings to the world of Django Web Framework </h1> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: import textwrap
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils     import timezone
from django.http      import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View
class HomePageView(View):
    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        c = {}
        return render(request, 'welcome.html', c)

Comment: please share more code in your views and add the trackback record. In your post not in your comment

Comment: hi I had provided my full views.py . It is my first application

Comment: welcome.html         <html>
            <head>
                <title>Greetings to Django</title>
            </head>
            <body>                
<h1 style="color:green;" align="center">Greetings to the world of Django Web Framework </h1>
            </body>
           </html>

Comment: read this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#url-argument-name

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter to `dispatch`, like all instance methods, should be `self`. `request` is passed as a keyword argument.

Note however that you should not be overriding dispatch. By doing so you are negating all the benefits of using class based views; you might as well use a standalone function. Instead, subclass TemplateView, set `template_name` as a class attribute, and define `get_context_data` when you actually need to pass some data to the template.

Answer (score 1):

As already you are called **view by name** then It would be much better you can simply import all views like :

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

and mostly we use camelcase to define view name as: **homePageView()**

please go through it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#url-argument-name

Comment: i made change as   url(r'^$', HomePageView.dispatch, name='home') in my hello/urls.py it starts working.

Comment: You should absolutely certainly not have made that change.

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py file, in a class function you need to use `self` as an argument.
Change this line `def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):` to `def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

```
class HomePageView(View): 
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        c = {} 
        return render(request, 'welcome.html', c)
```